# What is unextended OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, terminology

What does unextended OpenGL mean. Does it refer to the non-programmable/Fixed pipeline version without any extensions? Why is it "unextended".

Comment: It usually refers to the base OpenGL without any [extensions](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/extensions/), but what is the context you are seeing this in?

Comment: While reading about GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced extension.

Comment: No big deal. It describes what extension adds as opposed to what it was if it isn't present. Like 'unpatched' for other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just refers to OpenGL without [extensions](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/extensions/) or, depending on context, without any extensions relevant to the discussion.

For example, in the [`GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/KHR/blend_equation_advanced.txt) specification you were reading, "the standard blend modes provided by *unextended* OpenGL" just means the modes OpenGL offers by default. It uses "unextended" for clarity, to qualify that it is referring to OpenGL's set of blend modes not just without `GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced`, but also without any other extensions that might add more advanced blend modes as well.